# How to find and delete elements within a json array in mariadb or mysql

Tags: mysql, json, nosql, mariadb

I have this json in the 'data' field of a mariadb table and I need:

1. know if a value exists within eg: TN-17170 ": {" id_fact ":" 6 "}
   `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$**.TN-17170.id_fact') as exist from fact WHERE id ='6'`
   But this shows something like ['6'], I would like to just get '6'
2. In another sentence, if the value exists, delete it.
   I try with
   `` UPDATE `fact` set datos= JSON_REMOVE(data, '$.datos.TN-17170') WHERE id ='6' `` , but I can't.

Please help me organize the queries, there is not much practical documentation about the use of json in mariadb and I want to use these functions.

```
CREATE TABLE `fact` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

INSERT INTO `fact` (`id`, `data`) VALUES
(6, '{\"id\": \"23\", \"datos\": [{\"TN-17170\": {\"id_fact\": \"6\"}}, {\"TN-17171\": {\"id_fact\": \"6\"}}, {\"TN-17173\": {\"id_fact\": \"6\"}}, {\"TN-17127\": {\"id_fact\": \"6\"}}, {\"TN-17177\": {\"id_fact\": \"6\"}}, {\"TN-17397\": {\"id_fact\": \"6\"}}]}');

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$**.TN-17170.id_fact') as exist from fact WHERE id ='6' ;

SELECT * FROM fact ;

UPDATE `fact` set data= JSON_REMOVE(data, '$.datos.TN-17170') WHERE id ='6';
SELECT * FROM fact ;
```

[db example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=919246be77510456cce5047a61ddfb38)

Comment: I've not yet used the JSON function, don't have the version. (coming soon though) ... but MariaDB does have [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/) on the various JSON functions, some with a video too. I may be able to give a try at a db fiddle as well, if you can add the table structure and the complete row of data to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I have already edited the question and put the example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=919246be77510456cce5047a61ddfb38

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I've updated the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f91a3695f297f482b6aeeee12cb2b98f) to break up the various queries for checking. I'm still only getting the `["6"]` as well, and no success so far with the `json_remove` function either. May be much later today before I can try other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an index within square brackets(*0 in this case*) for pattern of `JSON_EXTRACT()` function in order to extract the content of an array :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.datos[0].TN-17170.id_fact') AS exist 
  FROM `fact` 
 WHERE id ='6';
```

and this can also be used within `JSON_REMOVE()` function :

```
UPDATE `fact` 
   SET data= JSON_REMOVE(data, '$.datos[0].TN-17170.id_fact') 
 WHERE id ='6';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=115b663f855d1ec266bf5305248455e1)</kbd>